# Irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$. and modular arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to show that 17 is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$. So, I suppose $17=ab$, Then, I consider the norm, $N$ and thus obtain:

$289=N(a)N(b)=(a^2-10b^2)(c^2-10d^2)$
Hence it suffices to consider the following two cases:

(1) $(a^2-10b^2)=17$ and $(c^2-10d^2)=17$

(2)$(a^2-10b^2)=-17$ and $(c^2-10d^2)=-17$

Now , $a^2\equiv 7 \pmod{10}$ is a consequence of the above case. Now, I am not sure what to do with the first case.

Please do not use reciprocity

Comment: you have to consider $N(a)=N(b)=-17,$ too.

Comment: Also, don’t use $a,b$ twice. Maybe name if $w=a+b\sqrt{10}$

Answer (score 1):

The first case implies $a^2\equiv 2\mod 5$. However, the only squares modulo $5$ are $0,1$ and $4$. So this case can't happen.

The second case implies $a\equiv -2\equiv 3\mod 5$, and  the above remark shows it can't happen either.

Answer (score 0):

In either case, we have $a^2-10b^2\equiv 0\mod 17$. If $b\equiv 0$, then $a\equiv 0$, so we $17^2$ divides $a^2-10b^2 = 17$, which is nonsense.

Thus we can divide by $b$, and letting $x=\frac{a}{b}$, we get $x^2\equiv 10\mod 17$. Thus by definition of the Jacobi symbol we must have $\left(\frac{10}{17}\right)=1$. But one can compute that actually we have $\left(\frac{10}{17}\right)=-1$, so this is a contradiction.

Comment: please look at my edit

Comment: @topologicalorientablesurface You don't need to use reciprocity. Just directly check if there exists some $x<17$ such that $x^2\equiv 10\mod 17$.

Comment: If no such x exists, then what does that mean and why?

Comment: @topologicalorientablesurface Clearly $x=ab^{-1}$ will always be equivalent mod $17$ to some $y$ with $0\leqslant y<17$. But then $y^2\equiv x^2 \equiv 10\mod 17$, contradicting the nonexistence of a $y<17$ with $y^2\equiv 10$.